# Nvd3 angular directive discrete chart column max width

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3-angular-directives to show graphs.

I have an issue with the discrete bar chart column width, when there is enough data the chart columns are in reasonable width.

but with a few data the columns are extremely wide.

my question is: is there a way to enforce max width on the colunms?
My Code:

```
                          <nvd3-discrete-bar-chart
                                data="vm.dateData"
                                id="byDateChart"
                                height="400"
                                margin="{right: -5}"
                                showXAxis="true"
                                showYAxis="true"
                                showValues="true"
                                valueformat="vm.vformat()"
                                yaxisshowmaxmin="false"
                                noData="You Have No History"
                                transitionduration="1000"
                                tooltips="true"
                                xaxisticksize="2"
                                xAxisTickFormat="vm.xAxisTickFormat()"
                                yAxisTickFormat="vm.yAxisTickFormat()">
                            <svg></svg>
                        </nvd3-discrete-bar-chart>
```

Thanks!